# DinD gitlab-runner : Warning service runner-xxx-project-xx-concurrent-x-docker-x probably didn't start properly

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I tested a gitlab-runner on a virtual machine, it worked perfectly. I followed this tutorial at part Use docker-in-docker executor :

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

When i register a runner with exactly the same configuration on my dev server, the runner is called when there is a commit but i got alot of errors :

```
*** WARNING: Service runner-XXX-project-XX-concurrent-X-docker-X probably didn't start properly.

ContainerStart: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-XXX-project-XX-concurrent-X-docker-X AS /runner-XXX-project-XX-concurrent-X-docker-X-wait-for-service/service (executor_docker.go:1337:1s)

DEPRECATION: this GitLab server doesn't support refspecs, gitlab-runner 12.0 will no longer work with this version of GitLab

$ docker info
error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.39/info: dial tcp: lookup docker on MY.DNS.IP:53: no such host
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I believe all these error are due to the first warning. I tried to :

- Add a second DNS with 8.8.8.8 IP to my machine, same error
- Add privileged=true manually in /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml, same error, so it's not due to the privileged = true parameter
- Replace tcp://docker:2375 by tcp://localhost:2375, can't find docker daemon on the machine when docker info

gitlab-ci.yml content :

```
 image: docker:stable
 stages :
  - build

 variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

 services:
  - docker:dind

 before_script:
  - docker info

 build-folder1:
   stage: build
   script:
    - docker build -t image1 folder1/
    - docker run --name docker1 -p 3001:5000 -d image1
   only: 
    refs:
     - dev
    changes:
     - folder1/**/*

 build-folder2:
   stage: build
   script:
     - docker build -t image2 folder2/
     - docker run --name docker2 -p 3000:3000 -d image2
   only:
     refs:
      - dev
     changes:
      - folder2/**/*
```

- If folder1 of branch dev is modified, we build and run the docker1
- If folder2 of branch dev is modified, we build and run the docker2

docker version on dev server :

```
docker -v 
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 3a232c8
```

gitlab-runner version on dev server :

```
gitlab-runner -v
Version:      11.10.1
```

Answer (score 3):

I will try to provide an answer for you, as I come to fix this same problem when trying yo run DinD.

This message:

> *** WARNING: Service runner-XXX-project-XX-concurrent-X-docker-X probably didn't start properly.

Means that either you have not properly configured your runner, or it is not linked by the `gitlab-ci.yml` file. You should be able to ckeck the ID of the runner used in the log page at Gitlab.

To start with, verify that you entered the **gitlab-runner register** command right, with the proper registration token.

Second, since you are setting a specific runner manually, verify that you have set some unique tag to it (eg. **build_docker**), and call it from your `gitlab-ci.yml` file. For example:

```
...
build-folder1:
   stage: build
   script:
    - docker build -t image1 folder1/
    - docker run --name docker1 -p 3001:5000 -d image1
   tags:
    - build_docker
...
```

That way it should work.